# How to check if columns in a large parquet file have been modified?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, pyspark

I frequently run a pyspark script on a large parquet file repository for data analysis. The files in this repository are periodically updated with (a) new rows and (b) different values for existing rows in each column.

I am wondering if there is a way to check if certain columns in a parquet file have been modified in some manner compared to a previous version, so that I can save time by not repeating my analysis when the columns have not been modified?

Comment: Is there a primary key in your parquet file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no property on the parquet format or spark to help off the shelf. You need to build metadata to help with operation.

You can use one column to store 'updated date' and another column to store a sequence of updated columns. You can partition the data by 'updated date' column using `partitionBy and saveAsTable` so that you can scan the lated updated records quickly.